# Visual Studio 2017 Live Visual Tree shows empty for WPF

Tags: wpf, debugging, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I installed VS 2017 v.15.6.3 and trying to debug a WPF application (running Test method to start WPF instance in same solution with attached process). Live Visual Tree shows blank and returns no result. I couldn't select any control to view in the visual tree. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I checked all options under Enable UI debugging Tools for XAML and valdiated `XamlDiagnostics.DLL` in the machine.

Comment: Welcome! We will probably need more information here so you have a better chance of getting your question answered. Can you get a super-minimal WPF application working at all? If you can, comparing it to your WPF app, where does it start to fail? Thanks

Comment: @mkumara, Live Visual Tree really has the default project type requirements: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/inspect-xaml-properties-while-debugging. If a simple WPF app works well in your side, one possible reason is that your project type doesn't really support this feature even if I didn't know that how you write this solution in your side. If you get any latest information, feel free to share it here.

Comment: I am able to live visual tree in new projects. In existing project running from Test, it didn't. thank you for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Visual Studio 2017 Live Visual Tree shows empty for WPF

I do not think Visual Studio support Live Visual Tree for test project even if it start WPF instance in same solution with attached process.

The application should be **WPF** for Live Visual Tree to work.

So, to get the Live Visual Tree, please debug the WPF application directly.

Hope this helps.